# Undefined offset in table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, undefined, offset

Can someone solve my problem? 
I got this error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant qty - assumed 'qty' in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\dede\transaksi.php on line 65
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\dede\transaksi.php on line 65

on this script, I want to multiply between  cost and qty, anyone know?

```
$select=mysql_query("Select nota.id_item,nota.qty,item.nama_item,item.cost_item FROM nota,item WHERE nota.id_item = item.id_item");
       while($data=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
       $sub=$_POST[$data[qty]] * $_POST[$data[cost_item]];
        echo"<tr>";
          echo"<td height=20 >$data[id_item]</td>";
          echo"<td height=20 >$data[nama_item]</td>";
          echo"<td height=20 >$data[cost_item]</td>";
          echo"<td height=20 >$data[qty]</td>";
          echo"<td height=20 >$data[qty]*$data[cost_item]</td>";
          echo"<td><a href=deleten.php?id=$data[id_item]>X</a></td>";
         echo"</tr>";}
```

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($_POST)` so we can see what you're getting sent to you?

Comment: you are not quoting your array index names. IE `$_POST[$data[qty]]` should be `$_POST[$data['qty']]` when not quoted it is looking for a CONSTANT variable that is named `qty` or whatever as the error message says.

Comment: That actually doesn't matter here, because PHP is assuming a string anyway. Example: https://eval.in/52747

Comment: Now see output thomas, I think it depends on error_reporting. Notice: `Use of undefined constant b - assumed 'b' in /tmp/execpad-41a28bcefc8a/source-41a28bcefc8a on line 9`

Comment: If you use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` then it will give notice as above.

Comment: The first notice is [explained in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down...

```
$select = mysql_query("Select nota.id_item,nota.qty,item.nama_item,item.cost_item FROM nota,item WHERE nota.id_item = item.id_item");
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
```

At this point, your `$data` variable should have 8 elements to it. Since you used [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), you'll have both numeric and associative keys. That is, your keys will be: `0, 1, 2, 3, id_item, qty, nama_item, cost_item`, and you can reference them either like this: `$data[1]`, or like this: `$data['qty']` (since they are indexed in order of the original query, the values of these two examples should be the same).

Now, I don't exactly know why you're using `$_POST`... If you wanted to get the cost multiplied by the quantity for the values you got from the database, you'd just do:

```
$sub = $data['qty'] * $data['cost_item'];
```

By the way, one more problem you're going to face is that PHP won't do string substitution for array members... at least not the way you have it here:

```
echo"<td height=20 >$data[qty]</td>";
```

Given that you fix `$data[qty]` to `$data['qty']`, you're still going to need to surround the whole thing in curly braces in order for it to print. Otherwise, you'll get a parsing error:

```
echo"<td height=20 >$data['qty']</td>";    // Bad
echo"<td height=20 >{$data['qty']}</td>";  // Good
```